# Passing in className to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to pass a `classname` to the `material-ui Button component` but can't seem to get it to work. Below are my attempts.

**Attempt 1**:

```
attributes.map((attribute, index) => {
  const classString = 'classes.button' + index;
  console.log(classString)
  return (
    <Button className={classString} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, attribute)}> 
     {attribute} 
    </Button>
  )}
)}
```

**Attempt 2**:

```
attributes.map((attribute, index) => {
  const classString = 'classes.button' + index;
  console.log(classString)
  return (
    <Button className={'${classString}'} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, attribute)}>
      {attribute}
    </Button>
  )}
)}
```

I have tried the classnames npm package as well but even that isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `classes` is an object with a key as `button`. // in material-ui example, they pass `classes` as `props`

Change your `classString` declaration a bit. Make sure that you are passing `classes` object and it has key named `button`.

```
attributes.map((attribute, index) => {
  const classString = classes.button + `${index}`; // best practice to add string to a number
  return (
    <Button className={classString} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, attribute)}> 
      {attribute} 
     </Button>
  )}
)}
```

If you are still facing the problem, the issue is with `classes` object. To test it change the line `const classString = classes.button +`${index}`;` to

`const classString = 'random-class';`

and check whether the button is getting the class `random-class`

**Edit:**

Since your `classes` object is something like this:

```
{
  class1: _class2-something-15443",
  class2: ....,
  ...
}
```

you should change `classString` accordingly.

change it to:
`` const classString = classes[`class${index}`]; ``

Comment: Even better: ```const classString = `${classes.button}${index};` ```. But I doubt that adding an array index to the css class is the right approach at all. It should either be an `id` instead if OP wants to apply css for specifically this button or it could be done differently by only using javascript.

Comment: Absolutely. But let him give a clarity on the issue. Is it with passing the className prop or the value coming in className prop

Comment: Yeah sure. It was just an additional comment so that in case OP did not think about this he may consider using another solution. That does not take away his chance to get a clarity on the issue as your answer provides him with the necessary hints.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I change it to classes.button + '${index}', it actually gives me a warning that says "unexpected template string expression", and it's still not working. And when I change it to 'const classString = 'classes.button' ' which is the original class, the button is still not getting the class, only when I remove the quotes does the button receive it.

Comment: I believed I have mis-typed back-ticks and it's not longer giving me the warning. However, the button is still not receiving the class. Is it possible that it has to do with the fact that I'm using withStyles?

Comment: Tried `const classString = 'random-class';`?

Comment: I tried `const classString = classes.button` and that works, but `const classString = 'classes.button'` still doesn't work.

Comment: One thing I noticed when I log `classes` is that I get an object that looks like `Object {class1: _class2-something-15443", etc}`, I have no idea what this means but I think this is related?

Answer (score 1):

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

- `className={yourVariableName}`
- `className={'redDiv'}`

Comment: with the limitation that `yourVariableName` should be a string or `null`/`undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The Material-UI implements CSS-in-js and uses the material-ui/styles 'withStyles' higher order component. Take a look at the Button demo on the site as it's extremely helpful https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/